# Norm of Multiplicative identity(If it exists) in a Normed Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I was reading Functional Analysis- Spectral theory by V S Sunder. This particular exercise asks what you can say about the norm of the multiplicative identity if it exists.

So from the definition of a normed algebra, if we denoted multiplicative identity by $1$ and some non-zero element x
$1x=x\implies ||x||\leq||1||||x||\implies 1\leq ||1||$ .

I guess that the norm of multiplicative identity will be $1$. But I am not able to derive the other inequality.

If someone can help, it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to derive the other inequality because you can't. In general, it isn't true that the multiplicative identity has norm $1$. Let's observe, first of all, that if $V$ is a normed space and if $p: V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a norm on $V$, then $\alpha p$ is a norm on $V$ with $\alpha > 0$ being a constant.

In particular, just consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the function $p(x) = \alpha |x|$, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for some constant $\alpha > 1$. Since this is an equivalent norm, $\mathbb{R}$ is clearly a Banach space under this norm. Moreover:
$$p(xy) = \alpha |xy| = \alpha |x| \cdot |y| \leq \alpha |x| \cdot \alpha |y| = p(x) p(y)$$
This shows that $\mathbb{R}$ is a Banach algebra with its usual multiplication. But now, let $x = 1$. Then, $p(1) = \alpha > 1$. So, $\mathbb{R}$ has an identity but the norm of this identity is not $1$. Of course, it is possible to take an arbitrary Banach algebra with identity and talk about its unitization; there's an equivalent norm that you can place on it which turns it into a unital Banach algebra. This construction should be available in most monographs on functional analysis that go through this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I know that any Banach algebra can be embedded in an unital Banach algebra. Does that make any change in the norm of the identity element?

Comment: Sure, the norm of the identity element in the new norm becomes $1$. In the old norm, it stays the same.